# Provisional Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, top-7, moderators

> #### Related:
>
> ### [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/728/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)

---

It is time for this community to contribute some names of members you would like to act as provisional Moderators. A handful of members will be appointed to this site at about 7 days into the public beta. They will fill the role of Moderators until you can have elections at the end of the beta period. More about this program here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

**Some guidelines:**

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

**The candidate:**

- Must be a currently registered user in good standing
- Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

Attribution goes to Jeff and ChrisF
([Blatantly stolen from Ivo Flipse and the great crowd at Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/moderator-nominations))

More information on how this process will work [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056) (meta.so) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) (blog).

---

**For further reading:** (thanks Bryant)

- [Moderation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderation)
- [Moderator Abilities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities)
- [Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators)

Comment: For my own reference, mostly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators

Answer (score 14):

I think, based on the evolution thus far of the site, any short list should include [@Bryant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/24/bryant), and am nominating him for his activity record and patience.

---

I accept the nomination. Brief blurb:

### [Bryant](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/24/bryant)

I am a relative newcomer to the SO family; I've benefited from Server Fault answers more than once, but have not been a participant in the community. I have been gaming for coming up on 25 years or so. My first RPG was *Tunnels & Trolls*, and my favorite Gencon purchase this year was an autographed *Monsters, Monsters* reprint.

I currently play a lot of 4e. When I lived in Boston, I played a lot of story games. I find that for the most part, I like games in general, although narrative-focused games tend to leave me cold. But I like thinking about those, too.

I believe in shaping a site by aggressively acting in the manner one wants to encourage. I suspect I'd have a ton to learn about moderating this style of site.

Comment: Thanks and I'm flattered! Does anyone know how much time we have to think about it? I don't want to say yes as a knee-jerk reaction, despite my sizable ego.

Comment: @Bryant: If the process works as it did on Gaming, there will come a point when moderators pro tem are promoted from the community by the StackExchange personnel. I don't know when that will happen, but you probably have a few days to think it through.

Comment: We have 7 days private beta, no? My gut tells me we'll have mods before public beta... but I have nothing to support this opinion.

Comment: Glad you're flattered even though I managed to mangle your name ;) (And my thanks to Eric Weilnau for fixing it)

Comment: @Richard: I don't remember, but I think we didn't have mods on gaming until a week or two into public beta.

Comment: I think Bryant would be an excellent moderator.

Comment: OK; I'm up for it if our community and the SO overlords want me. :)

Comment: Yes, Bryant please. :)

Comment: At first I was hesitant - I didn't want to just vote for the guy with the most rep - but Bryant's involvement in the community has already begun to establish him as a de facto leader.

Answer (score 8):

For his initiative in creating this 'thread' I nominate [@C. Ross](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/45/c-ross)

---

I accept.  Brief spiel about me.

### [C. Ross](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/45/c-ross)

I've been on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16487/c-ross) for over a year, and I am also an active participant on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16487/c-ross).  I've also  setup the [chat](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/temporary-chat-for-role-playing-games) (please join me there, it's been a great tool for other sites!).

I have played RPGs for over ten years now, and have experience playing and gm'ing (admittedly more playing).  I've primarily played D&D (3, 3.5, 4.0) and D20 Modern, though I've dabbled in other systems and even free form storytelling role playing.

As for my style I tend to be a little aggressive in closing questions.  I hope that the users of Role-playing Games will give me the opportunity to work with community as a moderator.

Comment: I second, not for the initiative on this thread, but for his insights here and on other SE network sites. I think "moderator material" is written all over C. Ross.

Answer (score 8):

I can nominate more than one person, right? [@mxyzplk](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/140/mxyzplk) is asking a ton of good meta questions and I'm learning from him, which is what I want in a moderator.

---

### [Mxyzplk](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/140/mxyzplk)

I’m a thirtysomething dad and IT professional living in the Austin, TX area. I started gaming way back in the day, 1982, with the TSR space opera game Star Frontiers. Since then I've been an avid roleplayer. I went to 5 Gen Cons, was a regional Triad for the RPGA's Living Greyhawk campaign, helped start a gaming club (the FORGE) in Memphis, TN, et cetera.  I use Server Fault mostly, the others less.

I GM and play a variety of RPGs; currently Pathfinder is in heavy rotation as well as various non-D&D-based games.  I also maintain a gaming blog, [Geek Related](http://mxyzplk.wordpress.com/).

In general I don't like pushy moderators on forum sites.  I plan to let viewpoints flourish but strictly maintain the SE format to distinguish this site from general forums.  I believe this could be a unique and invaluable resource if shepherded and wikignomed well.

Comment: I'd be willing to moderate. Thanks for thinking of me!

Comment: He'd be another excellent choice!  Second on him as well!

Comment: Thirded for both questions and answers.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly nominate more than one person.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to nominate [@RS Conley](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/93/rs-conley) -- he's sensible, brings a wealth of OSR/retro knowledge, and is supportive of all flavors of gaming.

Comment: I would second the @RS Conley nomination.  He's a well-rounded gamer, sensible, affable, and well thought of.

Comment: I am flattered and if accepted as moderator I would be able to spend some time doing this.

Comment: Thirded, I imagine a good moderator.